# Laravel 8 I cant verify image type

Tags: image, validation, laravel-8, laravel-api

Hello I can't verify my image type with `mimes:jpg,jpeg,png`

I am sending this to api

```
"images": [
    {
      "imageId": 0,
      "size": 1036822,
      "name": "scott-webb-hDyO6rr3kqk-unsplash.jpg",
      "type": "jpeg",
      "belongsTo": 0
    }
  ]
```

before this type was `'image/jpeg'`

but I get the same error:

```
images.0.type: Array(1)
0: "The images.0.type must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg."
```

This is validation:

```
$request->validate([
    'images.*.type' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg',
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

$this->validate($request,
['image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',]);

Comment: I did it like this but it still works:
        $request->validate(['image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',]):